# MultipleObjectsReturned

Tags: django, django-queryset

Quando eu crio dois tópicos com o mesmo nome, da erro:MultipleObjectsReturned

```
class ForumView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = 'forum/forum.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Thread.objects.filter()
        order = self.request.GET.get('order','')
        if order == 'views':
            queryset = queryset.order_by('-views')
        elif order == 'answers':
            queryset = queryset.order_by('-answers')
        return queryset
```

Como mudar a query para não dar erro com thread de mesmo nome?

Comment: Qual o stack trace da exceção?

Comment: Tenta substituir o Filter() por all() ou passar algum argumento para o filter()

Comment: Em qual linha o erro ocorre? Postar o stackTrace ajudaria bastante, como o @Ivella sugeriu